# Access SQL get data till current date not EOM

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is used in a Access program to get the data of the last month. How can I code it to get data to the current day?

```
 NPDateE = DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: do you want to code in access or sql-server? use only respective tags

Comment: if it is Access `NPDateE <= Date()`;

Answer (score 0):

`Date()` returns the current day.  To get all records till current day, your expression will have to be changed to

```
NPDateE <= Date()
```

For more information on `Date()`, you can refer to this [office tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: I changed it to M-0 and let the report run. Do you think that will work? its a 2 hour deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently in VBA are setting the variable *NPDateE* this way:

```
NPDateE = DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0))
```

all you need is this:

```
NPDateE = Date
```